# Button over a preferences ListView in ICS and Jelly Bean (API 15 / 16)

Tags: android, listview

I load a preferences screen with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/export_main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/export_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/entry_background" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/export_settings_list"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/export_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_file_upload_white_24"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The RecyclerView is the list where an XML preferences file is inflated. The rest of the layout, the FAB and the ImageView, are just additions to customize the preferences screen.

All of this works perfectly well on the latest Android versions, but on ICS and Jelly Bean (I did not try Kikat), the FloatingActionButton cannot receive any clicks and became a little transparent.

I tried a dozen of different things (with a standard button, a standard lisview etc.), but the button remains useless on the screen, the list item below is always clicked instead.

I think the problem might comes from the fact that I inflate an XML preferences file since I created the same layout with a standard list and the button is working well in any version.

Worst case scenario I will just load a specific layout for the old versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually finally succeeded to make it work.

In my question I was adding the button from the XML but the on click event could not be caught. I finally changed my code and added the button dynamically in the layout, and it worked!

I still can't explain why the click is possible when the button is added programmatically, maybe with the XML the button remains below the list...

Anyway here's the code:

```
    final ViewGroup innerContainer = (ViewGroup) exportView.findViewById(R.id.export_main_frame);
    final View innerView = super.onCreateView(inflater, innerContainer, savedInstanceState);
    if (innerView != null) {
        innerContainer.addView(innerView);

        // Add dynamically the FAB to export
        FloatingActionButton dynamicExportFAB = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
        dynamicExportFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_file_upload_white_24);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

        dynamicExportFAB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO
            }
        });

        innerContainer.addView(dynamicExportFAB, params);
    }
```