# Fab gets focus only sometimes

Tags: android, d-pad

I have a problem testing the focusability of my App with D-pad. Here there are two screenshots of my App:

[image]
[image]

In the picture of the left side, the fab is "outside(or below)" the list and after the last element it gets the focus when navigating down, so everything is ok in this case. The problem comes with the image of the right side. The fab is "inside" the listView and for that reason(I think but I'am not sure) it doesn't get ever the focus. Is there anything that can be done about it?

An enhacement would be that the fab would get the focus always before the list(that is immediately after the tabs), no matter where the fab is positioned at the momment in the layout, but the problem is that I don't know how to do it, since Android decides the focus order of my Layout.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
fragment_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    tools:mContext=".FragmentMain">
    <!---marginBottom for ads-->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpagerMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingTop="60dp"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                        android:id="@+id/chart"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        android:background="@drawable/progress"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"

                        android:visibility="visible"
                        tools:visibility="visible">

                    </ProgressBar>
                </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"


                />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- http://antonioleiva.com/floating-action-button/-->
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabMain"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_focusable_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_48"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/ad_bottom_bar"
        android:id="@+id/advBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

       />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

security_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- for statedrawable list to work we need to set background in cardview and
 immediate linearlayout. Also set android.clickable in cardview AND
 android:duplicateParentState in linearlayout-->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_security"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/overflow"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/si_card_view_content_padding"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/si_card_view_elevation"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/overflow"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_security">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/ticker"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"

                tools:text="GOOG" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/market"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="EQUITY" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/cardView"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_overflow_mini"
                android:tint="@color/gray700"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.carlos.capstone.customcomponents.AutoResizeTextView
                android:id="@+id/securityName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="Alphabet Inc." />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="@dimen/si_label_day"
                android:text="Day(max/min)"
                tools:text="Day(max/min)" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:textSize="@dimen/si_price_text_size"
                tools:text="710,89" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.9"
                android:orientation="vertical">



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.carlos.capstone.customcomponents.AutoResizeTextView
                        android:id="@+id/percentChange"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/si_percent_margin_top"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/si_percent_text_size"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        tools:text="-110.21%" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.carlos.capstone.customcomponents.AutoResizeTextView
                    android:id="@+id/dayMax"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray400"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    tools:text="716,49" />

                <com.carlos.capstone.customcomponents.AutoResizeTextView
                    android:id="@+id/dayMin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/si_min_padding_top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray400"
                    tools:text="706,02" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: may your xml implantation is wrong post your xml hear.

Comment: I got the same problem on a preferences list, it happens because the list item below is getting the focus and not the FAB. That's why it is working on the first screenshot.

Comment: @Carlos Do you get this problem on all versions? This problem happened for me on old API versions, not the latest ones.

Comment: sorry, I havent tested it in previous versions, this version is 22

Comment: @Yoann yes that is the problem, but how to solve it?

Comment: @Carlos Not solved yet... Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795953/button-over-a-preferences-listview-in-ics-and-jelly-bean-api-15-16

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate `Layout` and put your fab there. This will force that part to always be seen.

For example

```
<LinearLayout>
    //list stuff here
    <LinearLayout>
    //fab stuff
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the two layouts are in differents fragments

Comment: Futhermore, the user would need to navigate untill the end of the list to see the fab, if the list is one or two elements no problem, but on larger lists the fab is placed at the end, that is not a good behaviour of fab, that should be always and easy visible. Anyway thanks for your answer